# v7 Toolbar OptionsMenu Item to far right - how to add margin

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in my activity.

I added it into my layout for the activity as following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/add_contact_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:title="@string/add_contact_toolbar_title"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I inflate the options menu in onCreateOptionsMenu of the activity and I 
inflate my menu.xml :

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_contact_optionmenu_save"
        android:title="@string/add_contact_optionmenu_save"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

But unfortunately, the item appears way too far right and is too small:

[image]

How can I make it to appear like in all other apps? Bigger, and with more
right margin?

Cheers!

Comment: app:showAsAction="always|withText"  not sure but try that and see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well to move the `MenuItem` to a bit left from the right edge, you need to set `paddingRight` attribute to the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

```
android:paddingRight="20dp"
```

To change the size, add the following style `<item>` to your `App Theme`.

```
<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/ActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/ActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
```

```
<style name="ActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
       parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">48dp</item>
</style>
```

All this being said, a better design pattern is simply to go ahead and follow the `Material Design` guidelines. I would suggest you have an `icon` for `save` rather than the text.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. But...this is actually following the Material design guide lines!  https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-full-screen-dialogs

Comment: I meant this: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-specs The default size that you get for `MenuItem` in the `Toolbar` is the right one, because the `ActionBar` is designed with 56dp size. When you increase the text size of the MenuItem, you will lose the vertical alignment.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the link. Well then some google applications are not following their own guides? For example the notes app uses greater textsizes for right optionsmenu items.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **layout_marginEnd** to Toolbar worked for me

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
/>
```